# METAFONT failed for some reason, unable to find transcript file

Tags: miktex, windows, metafont

A simple latex document of mine is attempting to invoke the following, which fails

```
$ miktex-makepk --verbose tcit0800 525 600 0+525/600
Trying to make PK font tcit0800 at 525 DPI...
The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
Creating tcit0800.pk...
Running miktex-mf.exe...
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)


(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\tcit
0800.mf
(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\exba
se.mf)
(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\tcit
.mf
(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\txsy
mb.mf
 Ok
(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\exac
cess.mf
 Ok)
(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\txps
eudo.mf
 Ok)
(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\txac
cent.mf
 Ok [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [27] [29])
(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\txge
n.mf
 Ok [100] [109] [98] [99] [108])
(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\txsy
mbol.mf
 Ok [13] [18] [21] [22] [23] [24] [25] [26] [28] [31] [32] [36] [39] [44]
[45] [46] [42] [47] [60] [61] [62] [77] [79] [87] [110] [91] [93] [94] [95]
[96] [126] [127] [128] [129] [130] [131] [132] [133] [134] [135] [136] [137]
[138] [139] [140] [141] [142] [143] [144] [145] [146] [147] [148] [149]
[150] [151]
> 0 SSW 1 2 3 4 5 (WSW WNW NNW) NNE 6 7 8 9 (NNW WNW WSW) SSW 0
! Strange path (turning number is zero).
<to be read again>
                   ;
l.1373  & pulled_super_arc.e(6,7)(superpull);
                                               % left half of lower bowl
> 0 NNE 1 2 3 4 5 (ENE ESE SSE) SSW 6 7 8 9 (SSE ESE ENE) NNE 0
! Strange path (turning number is zero).
<to be read again>
                   ;
l.1374 ...oke super_arc.e(7,8) & super_arc.e(8,5);
                                                   % right half of lower bowl
> 0 SSW 1 2 3 4 5 (WSW WNW NNW) NNE 6 7 8 9 (NNW WNW WSW) SSW 0
! Strange path (turning number is zero).
<to be read again>
                   ;
l.1389  & pulled_super_arc.e(2,3)(superpull);
                                               % left half of upper bowl
> 0 NNE 1 2 3 4 5 (ENE ESE SSE) SSW 6 7 8 9 (SSE ESE ENE) NNE 0
! Strange path (turning number is zero).
<to be read again>
                   ;
l.1390 ...oke super_arc.e(3,4) & super_arc.e(4,1);
                                                   % right half of upper bowl
[152] [153] [154] [155] [156] [157] [158] [159] [160] [161] [162] [163]
[164] [165] [166] [167] [168] [169] [171] [172] [173] [174] [175] [177]
[176] [180] [181] [182] [183] [184] [187] [191] [214] [246])
(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\txit
lod.mf
 Ok [48] [49] [53] [54] [56] [57] [50] [51] [52] [55])
(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\txis
uper.mf
 Ok [185] [178] [179] [170] [186])
(C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/jknappen/ec\txif
ract.mf
 Ok [188] [189] [190]) ) ) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Font metrics written on tcit0800.tfm.
Output written on tcit0800.525gf (128 characters, 13672 bytes).
Transcript written on tcit0800.log.
METAFONT failed for some reason

Sorry, but makepk did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log
```

The referenced log file, `C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log`, contains only the following, which isn't anything new

```
2020-01-08 13:07:59,259Z INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: "C:\Users\wiese\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makepk.exe" --verbose tcit0800 525 600 0+525/600
2020-01-08 13:07:59,264Z INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font tcit0800 at 525 DPI...
2020-01-08 13:07:59,277Z INFO  makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
2020-01-08 13:07:59,303Z INFO  makepk - Creating tcit0800.pk...
2020-01-08 13:07:59,310Z INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2020-01-08 13:07:59,311Z INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input tcit0800"
2020-01-08 13:08:00,133Z INFO  makepk - METAFONT failed for some reason
2020-01-08 13:08:00,139Z FATAL miktex-makepk - No such file or directory: path="tcit0800.log"
2020-01-08 13:08:00,139Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: path="tcit0800.log"
2020-01-08 13:08:00,139Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\File.cpp
2020-01-08 13:08:00,139Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 149
```

I'm holding out hope that `Transcript written on tcit0800.log.` might give some more clues to this failure. But where is this file? It's not in my working directory, nor is it in the same directory as the other log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `touch tcit0800.log` first seems to workaround the problem, but this looks to be a bug in `miktex-makepk` (https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/448)