# METAFONT failed for unknown reasons

Tags: miktex, metafont

I encounter with a METAFONT error while compiling Latex file (with beamer package). Some people in this community also faced it, but proposed solutions were useless (updating Miktex & refreshing font map files)

The log refers to miktex-makepk.log, which listing I put below

miktex-makepk.log's listing:

> !   1. 2021-10-08 17:23:46,233+0200 INFO miktex-makepk - this process (11604) started by 'pdflatex' with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose ecso0800 525 600 0+525/600 2. 2021-10-08 17:23:46,234+0200 INFO makepk - Trying to make PK font ecso0800 at 525 DPI... 3. 2021-10-08 17:23:46,237+0200 INFO makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour 4. 021-10-08 17:23:46,240+0200 INFO makepk - Creating ecso0800.pk... 5. 2021-10-08 17:23:46,241+0200 INFO makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe... 6. 2021-10-08 17:23:46,241+0200 INFO makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input ecso0800" 7. 2021-10-08 17:23:46,244+0200 INFO miktex-makepk.core - start process: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input ecso0800" 8. 2021-10-08 17:23:47,661+0200 INFO makepk - METAFONT failed for some reason 9. 2021-10-08 17:23:47,661+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecso0800. 10. 2021-10-08 17:23:47,661+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecso0800. 11. 2021-10-08 17:23:47,661+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 12. 2021-10-08 17:23:47,661+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 13. 2021-10-08 17:23:47,661+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0 14. 2021-10-08 17:23:47,675+0200 INFO miktex-makepk - this process (11604) finishes with exit code 1 15. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,497+0200 INFO miktex-makepk - this process (11948) started by 'pdflatex' with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose ecso0800 525 600 0+525/600 16. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,499+0200 INFO makepk - Trying to make PK font ecso0800 at 525 DPI... 17. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,501+0200 INFO makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour 18. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,504+0200 INFO makepk - Creating ecso0800.pk... 19. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,505+0200 INFO makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe... 20. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,505+0200 INFO makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input ecso0800" 21. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,505+0200 INFO miktex-makepk.core - start process: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input ecso0800" 22. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,942+0200 INFO makepk - METAFONT failed for some reason 23. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,942+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecso0800. 24. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,942+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecso0800. 25. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,942+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 26. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,942+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 27. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,943+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0 28. 2021-10-08 17:23:49,956+0200 INFO miktex-makepk - this process (11948) finishes with exit code 1 29. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,061+0200 INFO miktex-makepk - this process (8620) started by 'pdflatex' with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose ecso0800 525 600 0+525/600 30. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,063+0200 INFO makepk - Trying to make PK font ecso0800 at 525 DPI... 31. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,065+0200 INFO makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour 32. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,068+0200 INFO makepk - Creating ecso0800.pk... 33. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,069+0200 INFO makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe... 34. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,069+0200 INFO makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input ecso0800" 35. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,069+0200 INFO miktex-makepk.core - start process: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input ecso0800" 36. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,497+0200 INFO makepk - METAFONT failed for some reason 37. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,497+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecso0800. 38. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,497+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecso0800. 39. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,497+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 40. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,497+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 41. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,497+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0 42. 2021-10-08 17:23:52,511+0200 INFO miktex-makepk - this process (8620) finishes with exit code 1 43. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,327+0200 INFO miktex-makepk - this process (1772) started by 'pdflatex' with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose ecso0800 525 600 0+525/600 44. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,328+0200 INFO makepk - Trying to make PK font ecso0800 at 525 DPI... 45. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,331+0200 INFO makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour 46. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,334+0200 INFO makepk - Creating ecso0800.pk... 47. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,335+0200 INFO makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe... 48. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,335+0200 INFO makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input ecso0800" 49. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,335+0200 INFO miktex-makepk.core - start process: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input ecso0800" 50. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,755+0200 INFO makepk - METAFONT failed for some reason 51. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,755+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecso0800. 52. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,755+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - METAFONT failed on ecso0800. 53. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,755+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 54. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,755+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 55. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,755+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0 56. 2021-10-08 17:23:54,769+0200 INFO miktex-makepk - this process (1772) finishes with exit code 1

Comment: possible duplicate of this one?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/523414/15036

Comment: or this?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152721/problems-with-fonts/152749